# Полноэкранное расширение QML QT

Tags: qt, qt5, qml

Как реализовать полноэкранное расширение окна в QML (Android)
Без потери позиций объектов

Comment: используй резиновую верстку

Comment: Резиновая верстка это лейауты (Layout)   :)

Comment: можно ещё якорить